# Importing and plotting a csv file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a big csv file, here is some of the data from it:

```
"C1_E1",,,,,
"Time","Force","Disp.","Stress","Strain","Stroke"
"sec","N","mm","MPa","%","mm"
"0","0.1192093","0","0.003017193","0","0"
"0.01","0.09536743","2.083333E-05","0.002413754","1.621271E-05","2.083333E-05"
"0.02","0.09536743","0.00025","0.002413754","0.0001945525","0.00025"
"0.03","0.09536743","0.0013125","0.002413754","0.001021401","0.0013125"
"0.04","0.09536743","0.003604167","0.002413754","0.002804799","0.003604167"
"0.05","0.09536743","0.006875","0.002413754","0.005350194","0.006875"
"0.06","0.09536743","0.01104167","0.002413754","0.008592736","0.01104167"
"0.07","0.09536743","0.01602083","0.002413754","0.01246757","0.01602083"
"0.08","0.09536743","0.02191667","0.002413754","0.01705577","0.02191667"
"0.09","0.09536743","0.028625","0.002413754","0.02227626","0.028625"
"0.1","0.09536743","0.035875","0.002413754","0.02791829","0.035875"
"0.11","3.910065","0.04352083","0.09896392","0.03386835","0.04352083"
"0.12","13.39118","0.05145833","0.3389313","0.0400454","0.05145833"
"0.13","18.46155","0.05989583","0.4672626","0.04661154","0.05989583"
"0.14","23.57165","0.06875","0.5965995","0.05350194","0.06875"
```

I'm trying to plot the stress and strain columns using numpy and matplotlib so I wrote the following code:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stress_data = genfromtxt('C1-E1.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=3, usecols=([3]))
strain_data = genfromtxt('C1-E1.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=3, usecols=([4]))
print(stress_data[:10], strain_data[:10])

map(float, stress_data)
map(float, strain_data)

print(stress_data[:10], strain_data[:10])

plt.xlabel ('x stuff')
plt.ylabel ('y stuff')
plt.title('my test result')
plt.plot(strain_data[:10], stress_data[:10])
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the output is

```
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan] [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan] [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

and of course no plot is made. I'm sure there is a problem in genfromtxt because if I set  dtype=("|S20") then I get

```
[b'"0.003017193"' b'"0.002413754"' b'"0.002413754"' b'"0.002413754"'
 b'"0.002413754"' b'"0.002413754"' b'"0.002413754"' b'"0.002413754"'
 b'"0.002413754"' b'"0.002413754"'] [b'"0"' b'"1.621271E-05"' b'"0.0001945525"' b'"0.001021401"'
 b'"0.002804799"' b'"0.005350194"' b'"0.008592736"' b'"0.01246757"'
 b'"0.01705577"' b'"0.02227626"']
```

which messes up the plot due to 1.621271E-05 being in scientific notation. Is there a way that I extract the data from the csv file AND convert it to a format that can handle scientific notation so that I can plot and analyze it?

Sorry for the long post but I don't know where to turn to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to work on csv file, the pandas library is really usefull.

Here, it makes everything much simpler:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data_1.csv',header=1)

df =df[1:].astype(float)  # Deletes the first row as it contains the unit and is not usefull if you want to plot the data, and convert the dataframe type to float
```

To plot the Force as a function of the time, you just have to do the following:

```
plt.plot(df['Time'],df['Force'])
```

Comment: This is a perfect implementation of dataframes. Nice work!